# addClass/removeClass on HTML menu isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've got a problem with getting my navigation bar to work. This probably is very easy to solve but i've been trying things for ages and can't get it to work. For CSS purposes i want the list item in the nav bar to get the class 'selected' when clicked and removed when a different nav bar item is clicked. For some reason it doesn't work. i'll show the code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('ul.navigation li a').click(function(){ 
              $('ul.navigation li a').removeClass('selected');
              $(this).addClass('selected');
            });
        </script>
```

I put this part in the `<head>...</head>`

This is the navigation bar which it's not having any effect on:

```
<div id="menuWrapper">  
     <nav>
       <ul class="navigation underlinemenu" id="gooeymenu">
                  <li id="home" class="selected"><a href="/html/index.php">Home</a></li>
                  <li id="work"><a href="/html/work.php">Work</a></li>
                  <li id="services"><a href="/html/services.php">Services</a></li>
                  <li id="about"><a href="/html/about.php">About me</a></li>
                  <li id="contact"><a href="/html/contact.php">Contact</a></li>                  
       </ul>
     </nav>
</div>
```

Now when i go to the browser and inspect the element it doesn't show any indication of adding the class 'selected' to the clicked menu item. When i check the console it gives some sort of error about the `$('ul.navigation li a').click(function(){` part of the javascript saying it isn't a function.

I hope this has explained my problem, i still think it's probably easy to solve but i've been stuck on this for an entire day so i hope anyone here can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Always wire up your events within a [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

If you apply the .ready function to the document, you ensure that your events are wired up. [Read here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) for a brief introduction on using `$(document).ready()`

```
//Wait for the DOM to load and be ready:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.navigation li a').click(function(){ 
        //Find the navigation link that is actually with the 'selected' class.
        $('ul.navigation li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. Could it possibly be something else?

Comment: @ChrisVossen: See my edit, you were applying the wrong jQuery selector. It should work for you know.

Comment: i tried everything what you said, i'm sorry to say this but it's still not working, maybe it has something to do with the jquery plugin i'm using; 'gooeymenu'.

Answer (score 0):

The element you are adding the 'selected' class doesn't look right.

In your html markup, you have the `<li class='selected'><a href=''>` but in your javascript you are removing and adding the `selected` class on the `a` element.

So you want to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.navigation li a').click(function(){
    $('ul.navigation li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Unless you meant to have the class on the `a` element, then just your initial HTML was wrong, and then Sergio's solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the "selected" class in the "LI" element

```
<ul class="navigation underlinemenu" id="gooeymenu">
                  <li id="home" class="selected"><a href="/html/index.php">Home</a></li>
                  <li id="work"><a href="/html/work.php">Work</a></li>
                  <li id="services"><a href="/html/services.php">Services</a></li>
                  <li id="about"><a href="/html/about.php">About me</a></li>
                  <li id="contact"><a href="/html/contact.php">Contact</a></li>                  
</ul>
```

but in your javascript you are removing and adding the "selected" class on the "A" element

So try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('ul.navigation li a').click(function(){ 
                  $('ul.navigation li').removeClass('selected');
                  $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    });
});
```